# Accessing Methods in Ruby Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I'm writing my first Ruby module and I have this:

/app/module/test_modules/test.rb

test.rb looks similar to:

```
module TestModules
  module Test

    def test
      puts 'this is a test'
    end
  end
end
```

When I call the following from console, I get:

```
(main)> TestModule::Test.test
//NoMethodError: private method `test' called for TestModules::Test:Module
```

How do I make test() visible?

Comment: `NoMethodError: private method 'test' called for TestModules::Test:Module` caused by http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/test

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is there something I can do to improve the question?

Comment: Possibly because this is an extremely simple Ruby question, and you misunderstood what was happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling a class method, whereas you defined `test` as an instance method. You could call it the way you want if you used the module via `include` or `extend`. [This article](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) does a good job explaining.

```
module TestModules
  module Test
    def self.test
      puts 'this is a test'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the same error when I call TestModules::Test.test

Comment: @doremi What version of ruby are you using? It works on Ruby 1.9.2-p290.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p194 - I just restarted the console and am now getting a different error. It could be because I broke something else. I'm looking ...

Comment: Do you know why I can't call TestModule::Test.new.test? I get undefined method `new' for TestModule::Test::Module

Comment: TestModules:Test is a module, not a class (I think Module inherits from Class, but I'm pretty sure instances of Module don't expose new).

Answer (score 1):

Also,

1)

```
module TestModules
  module Test
    def test
      puts 'this is a test'
    end

    module_function :test
  end
end
```

2)

```
module TestModules
  module Test
    extend self
    def test
      puts 'this is a test'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `module_function` method, which is interesting. I don't think the second method is a wise idea though; it works, but could really tie someone up if they weren't aware that it was there.

Comment: `extend self` is common practice for making modules testable

Answer (score 1):

The way that you have defined your method, it is a method on an instance of `Test` - thus it would work if you did:

```
blah = TestModule::Test.new
blah.test
```

*note* - and do use it this way, you would need to define `Test` as a `class` not a `module`

If you want the function to work on the class itself, then you need to define it like so:

```
def self.test
    ....
end
```

And then you can do `TestModules::Test.test`

Answer (score 0):

the test method you defined is instance method...try this

```
module TestModules
  module Test
    def self.test
      puts 'this is a test'
    end
  end
end
```

now you can call the method by this TestModules::Test.test